# Strong or weak declaration to UIImageView and UIImage properties embedded in UIScrollView?

Tags: properties, ios6, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIScrollview embedded in a NavController, both dragged out in the iOS6 storyboard. In my scrollViewController viewDidLoad, I programatically add a UIImageView and keep a property for the image that goes into that UIImageView.

```
@interface MyScrollViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image;

@end
```

Dragging out the ScrollView in the storyboard and hooking up the outlet made this a weak property by default, but what is the best practice for the other two properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest versions of Xcode default to using `strong`. If you use `weak` you may end up with compiler warnings about accessing a weak variable multiple times in a given scope. So just use `strong` for everything unless you have a good reason not to.